# JSON- Regex to identify a pattern in JSON

Tags: json, python-3.x, regex, large-data

I'm new to Python3  and I am working with large JSON objects. I have a large JSON object which has extra chars coming in between two JSON objects, in between the braces.

For example:

```
{"id":"121324343", "name":"foobar"}3$£_$£rvcfddkgga£($(>..bu&^783 { "id":"343554353", "name":"ABCXYZ"}'
```

These extra chars could be anything alphanumeric, special chars or ASCII. They appear in this large JSON multiple times and can be of any length. I'm trying to use regex to identify that pattern to remove them, but regex doesn't seem to work. Here is the regex I used:

```
(^}\n[a-zA-Z0-9]+{$)
```

Is there a way of identifying such patter using regex in python?

Comment: Your regex contains \n but the line you provided is on a single line, which is it?

Comment: For the example you are showing: `"}.+{"` is enough, but I would assume that this won't pass all test cases. If you know the pattern of the json will be `dict(id=number, name=string)` you can also filter on that instead. Example: `'{\s?"id":"\d+", "name":"\w+"}'` (for your provided example).

Comment: I am just concerned about  `r'(?<=})([^}{]+)(?={)'` if the `{` appears in the the char string is the issue as it should identify `{" `to identify the new object is tarting

Comment: @Thymen Filtering the json on the dict pattern sounds more apt. But it is large data will it affect the performance

Comment: Do the objects contain nested braces?

Comment: @SinnyS, it shouldn't have a noticeable difference, between filtering on the dictionary pattern or the removal pattern. I just think that the dictionary pattern is more robust against handling nested objects etc... But for the example you show both option will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select the dictionary data based on `named capture groups`. As a bonus, this will also ignore any `{` or `}` within the extra chars.

The following pattern works on the provided data:

```
"\"id\"\:\"(?P<id>\d+?)\"[,\s]+\"name\"\:\"(?P<name>[ \w]+)\""
```

#### Example

```
import re
from pprint import pprint

string = \
    """
    {"id":"121324343", "name":"foobar"}3$£_$£rvcfdd{}kgga£($(>..bu&^783 { "id":"343554353", "name":"ABC XYZ"}'
    """

pattern = re.compile(pattern="\"id\"\:\"(?P<id>\d+?)\"[,\s]+\"name\"\:\"(?P<name>[ \w]+)\"")
pprint([match.groupdict() for match in pattern.finditer(string=string)])
```

- Output

```
[{'id': '121324343', 'name': 'foobar'}, {'id': '343554353', 'name': 'ABC XYZ'}]
```

- Test it out yourself: https://regex101.com/r/82BqbE/1

#### Notes

For this example I assume the following:

- `id` only contains integer digits.
- `name` is a string that can contain the following characters `[a-zA-Z0-9_ ]`. (this includes white spaces and underscores).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the whole json is a single line, and there are no }{ inside the fields themselves, this should be enough

```
In [1]: import re

In [2]: x = """{"id":"121324343", "name":"foobar"}3$£_$£rvcfddkgga£($(>..bu&^783 { "id":"343554353", "name":"ABCXYZ"}"""

In [3]: print(re.sub(r'(?<=})[^}{]+(?={)', "\n", x))
{"id":"121324343", "name":"foobar"}
{ "id":"343554353", "name":"ABCXYZ"}
```

You can check the regex here https://regex101.com/r/leIoqE/1

Comment: In this solution if the chars has { or } it doesn't work